# Java generated Token not random - but what is it?

Tags: java, function, session, random, token

I am told to analyse the behavior of a web application and noticed that it generates password reset tokens based on the username+password combination. That means that if username and password combination of the account stays the same during the resets, the generated reset token stays also the same. 
So it is NOT random and not based on a time stamp or anything that changes frequently.

It does not look random to me at all. But what is it? 
I checked several Java functions like UUID, that generate tokens, but their output does not look like the tokens I am looking at.

Has anyone an idea what (Java function) generates this kind of tokens?

```
Account B
token=YwQAAAAAAAAmONpWfOI-dGQoZBbXxUaApbRQ7E
token=YwQAAAAAAAADIDSPpW_5vC8AvpNTi5LIgQZ080
token=YwQAAAAAAAAg5NcxcGeRWXA2m_K0cm0TNx8rO8
token=YwQAAAAAAAA0H4tkoER8tDfMR_V_TT3BPfC43g
token=YwQAAAAAAAApFrrJCJvb_zH0p5f-HkIt7EtWgA
token=YwQAAAAAAAAiDeQFrxpTSwrFNCV4AQW0sdoiyw

Account A
token=TwQAAAAAAAAi6M6tduIa6EdB3-VB1J_l8Cyza8
token=TwQAAAAAAAAM-yFuFKebUZA-2q0YgwnJeGrZuo
token=TwQAAAAAAAAg0We7RWTMM9PYv68RCJMUG_MuBw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this looks like a Base64 enoded something. Try to decode your token with Base64 and look what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I thought that "_" and "-" could not appear in a base64 string, but I checked Wikipedia and it say that there is a variant called "Base64 with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet (RFC 4648 'base64url' encoding)", that includes "_" and "-". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 0):

I think they are doing something like this to generate a base65 compressed string

[Sign a string using SHA1, then shrink it using url-safe base65](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1004/)